# How to add a regex pattern to response header in Swagger documentation using Springfox?

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, springfox

My service is returning response headers that follow a regex pattern. I am using Springfox to generate the swagger.

I have added this annotation in my controller-

```java
@ApiOperations(
    responseHeaders = {
        @ResponseHeader(name="header-name", response=String.class)
    }
)
```

This is generating the header response in Swagger like this-

```yaml
headers:
  header-name:
    type: string
```

Is there a way to add a **pattern** in the generated Swagger like this-

```yaml
headers:
  header-name:
    type: string
    pattern: "^[^*]+$"
```